# Nil errors in creating a hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running into several syntax and nil issues when trying to create this hash `idea_benefit_count`.

```
@idea = @domain.ideas
@idea_evaluations = Array.new()
@idea.each do |idea|
  @idea_evaluations << idea.evaluations
end

@idea_benefit = []
if !@idea_evaluations.nil?
  @idea_evaluations.each do |eval|
    @idea_benefit << eval.benefit
  end
  @idea_benefit_count = Hash.new(0)
  @idea_benefit.flatten.each { |idea_benefit| @idea_benefit_count[idea_benefit] += 1 }
end
```

An `idea has_many domains`, so `@idea` should be all of the ideas that has a given `@domain`.

`@idea_evaluations` is an array of all evaluations that `belong_to` a specific `idea`.

`@idea_benefit` is an array of arrays that holds all of each evaluation's `benefit` entries. example output: `[["happier_customers"], ["happier_employees"], ["happier_employees", "decreased_costs"], ["happier_employees"]]`

`idea_benefit_count` reads `idea_benefit` and counts how many of each type of benefit an idea has.  The output of `idea_benefit_count`  based on the above `idea_benefit` array is `{"happier_customers"=>1, "decreased_costs"=>1, "happier_employees"=>3}`

(Hopefully this context covers everything)

My current error is `undefined method 'benefit'` on the line `@idea_benefit << eval.benefit`.  `Benefit` is an attribute of `evaluation`, so it should output something like `["happier_customers"]`.

I realize this code is a bit of a mess, so any suggestions would be super helpful on getting the entire thing working. A big problem is checking to see if there are `evaluations` belonging to an `idea`, because if this comes back `nil` it throws an error.  Tried to fix that with the `if !@idea_evaluations.nil?` check, but haven't been able to test it yet because of the `undefined method 'benefit'` error.

EDIT

```
@idea_evaluations = Array.new()
@idea.each do |idea|
  @idea_evaluations << idea.evaluations
end
@idea_evaluations.flatten!

@idea_benefit = []
unless !@idea_evaluations.nil?
  @idea_evaluations.each do |eval|
    @idea_benefit << eval.benefit
  end
  @idea_benefit_count = Hash.new(0)
  @idea_benefit.flatten.each { |idea_benefit| @idea_benefit_count[idea_benefit] += 1 }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem that I see if I understand what you are trying to do is the way you are dumping idea.evaluations into @idea_evaluations.
@idea_evaluations is going to be an array of arrays of evaluations not an array of evaluations as you think.
e.g. `[[eval1,eval2],[eval3,eval4,eval5]]` instead of `[eval1, eval2, eval3, eval4, eval5]`

when you try to access the benefit, it attempts to look for a benefit method for the array which does not exist.

try altering

```
@idea.each do |idea|
  @idea_evaluations << idea.evaluations
end
```

to be

```
@idea.each do |idea|
  @idea_evaluations << idea.evaluations
end
@idea_evaluations.flatten!
```

also in ruby you usually don't do

```
if !condition
```

you normally do

```
unless condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to build up the array (or an ActiveRecord scope for better efficiency).

```
@idea_evaluations = @domain.ideas.map(&:evaluations)

# Remove nil values before moving on to the next chunk.
@idea_evaluations.reject! { |i| i.nil? }
@idea_benefits = @idea_evaluations.map(&:benefit)
```

If you go with the scope approach, it would look similar to the following:

```
# in Benefit.rb 
scope for_domain ->(domain_id){ joins(:evaluation => :idea).where(idea: {domain_id: domain_id}) }

# called like this 
@idea_benefits = Benefit.for_domain(@domain.id)
```

`inject` is a useful tool to summarize information.

```
@idea_benefits .inject({}) do |eval, result|
  result[eval] += 1 
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this entire snippet can be replaced by:

```
@idea_benefit_count  = 
  @idea.flat_map(&:evaluations)
       .flat_map(&:benefit)
       .each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) {|k, h| h[k] += 1}
```

Comment: this gave me `SyntaxError: (irb):47: syntax error, unexpected '.'
          .each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) {|k, h| h[k] += 1}`     I'd like to use this to make it more succinct if possible, you know why that error is thrown?

Comment: It could be a couple things... are you sure you copy-pasted everything all at once and not line-by-line?

Comment: Yes, I put it in all at once?